# Header and footer layout

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

this is my second question regarding more or less the same topic, since I am still struggling with it.

This is the layout I need to build:

[image: Layout]

**Also important:**

- The header and the footer contain buttons, info but shouldn't be included in the page transitions (eg. shouldn't fade in or fade out).
- In the end I just want the controls inside the "Page w/ content" (see picture below) area to be animated (fade in/fade out, etc) between the different pages.

**What I got so far:**

- Header and Footer are user controls;
- Page w/ content is a Lockablepivot (with headers hidden), and I use the pivot items to switch between the different content I want.

**Problems:**

- I havent been able to put the Islocked = true working (it always gives me a null ref excep);
- A pivot item is not really a page, so If the user for presses the back button it leaves the app (I think I can probably solve this by overriding the back button etc..);
- I don't know if its easy or even doable to change the pivot items animations (haven't researched much about this one).

**Ok, so my real question:**

What other options do I have?

- Using a ContentPresenter in the "Page w/ content" area to show me another xaml page? I read something about this being not good at all;
- Do everything in one page but dynamically and through the code add, delete, fade in, fade out all the controls ?

Any ideas? What about performance? Which one should perform best?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put an `Header` and `Footer` controls to a each page and make any animations with `Content` control you like